# Socket Hang Up { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }

Tags: node.js, web-services, api, sockets, http

I want to hit API in `Node.js` for connecting with SOAP and HTTPS. When I hit the URL for performing function with HTTPS request, I used the following code for connection with SOAP Server for performing data transfer. But it is showing an error:

> { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }:

```
exports.check=function(req,res) {
    //Add SSL to communicate with SOAP
    var sslRootCAs = require('ssl-root-cas/latest')
        .inject()
        .addFile( __dirname + '/Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4.cer' );

    var body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
        '<!—Worked Example 1: Birth Request -->' +
        '<RegBirths SchemaVersion="1.0" ProgramName="CTWSProg" ProgramVersion="1b" RequestTimeStamp="2001-12-17T09:30:47-05:00" >' +
            '<Authentication>' +
                '<CTS_OL_User Usr="111-111-111" Pwd="m0nster"/>' +
            '</Authentication>' +
            '<Births TxnId="123889">' +
                '<Birth RowNum="1" Etg="UK520202500138" Dob="2004-03-01" Brd="HF" Sex="f" EId="111222333" GdEtg="UK560002400063"' +
                    'BLoc="20/002/0001" PLoc="01/001/0001" PSLoc="04" IWarn="n"/>' +
                '<Birth RowNum="2" Etg="UK240001300777" Dob="2004-03-09" Brd="HF" Sex="f" EId="111222333" GdEtg="UK560002100018"' +
                    'BLoc="20/002/0001" PLoc="01/001/0001" PSLoc="04" IWarn="n" />' +
            '</Births>' +
        '</RegBirths>';

    var body2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
            '<soap:Body>' +
                '<TransferData xmlns="http://www.defra.gov.uk">' +
                    '<username>' + username + '</username>' +
                    '<password>' + password + '</password>' +
                    '<serviceName>DEFRA-CTWS-FULL-PROVING</serviceName>' +
                    '<data>'+ body +'</data>' +
                    '<type>Register_Births_Asynchronous-V1-0</type>' +
                '</TransferData>' +
            '</soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    var postRequest = {
        host : "hostman.com",
        path: "/abcxyz.asmx?WSDL",
        port: 443,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/xml',
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8',
            'SOAPAction': "https://www.axys.com/TransferData",
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body2)
        }
    };

    var buffer = "";

    var req = http.request( postRequest, function( res ) {
        console.log( res );
        var buffer = "";
        res.on( "data", function( data ) { buffer = buffer + data; } );
        res.on( "end", function( data ) { console.log( buffer ); } );
        res.on('error', function (err) { console.log( "----ERROR----" ); console.log(err);});
    });
    // req.on('error', function(err) {
    //     console.log( "----ERROR----" ); console.log(err);
    // });
    // `req`.on('socket', function (socket) {
    //   console.log(socket)
    //     socket.setTimeout(3000);  
    //     socket.on('timeout', function() {
    //         req.abort();
    //     });
    // });
    req.on('error', function(err) {
        if (err.code === "ECONNRESET") {
            console.log("Timeout occurs");
            //specific error treatment
        }
    });
    req.write( body );
    req.end();
}
```